# Create per-object ACL in AWS with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, acl

I am attempting to create a per-object ACL using Terraform in AWS.

Terrform lets me create a per-bucket ACL (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_acl), which I can also create in the Management Console. However, I don't appear to be able to create a ACL for a single file/object in S3 using Terraform. I'm able to do this with the Management Console, so I should be able to do it with Terraform, but I cannot find any examples/APIs that would allow this.

How do I set an ACL on a single file/object in S3 with Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws_s3_object` itself has an `acl` argument: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object#acl .

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you. I feel silly not thinking of this myself. :)